# iOS UI Testing: Cant Access elements - not in Elementtree

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, testing

Im am new to iOS UI Testing, and ive encountered a Problem.

I have a Cell in a TableView that expands on click. But i can not access any of the elements that were expanded. I Printed out the elementtree and noticed that they are not contained in the tree:

```
Table 0x608000379a40: traits: 35192962023424, {{0.0, 290.0}, {320.0, 234.0}}
                        Cell 0x608000379b00: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 290.0}, {320.0, 85.5}}
                          StaticText 0x608000379bc0: traits: 8589934656, {{93.0, 298.0}, {186.0, 16.0}}, label: 'Test Preview'
                          StaticText 0x608000379c80: traits: 8589934656, {{93.0, 316.0}, {186.0, 16.0}}, label: '1234'
                          StaticText 0x608000379d40: traits: 8589934656, {{93.0, 334.0}, {186.0, 16.0}}, label: 'grün'
                          Button 0x608000379e00: traits: 8589934593, {{93.0, 350.0}, {186.0, 25.0}}, label: 'bottomArrow'
                          Button 0x608000379ec0: traits: 8589934593, {{287.0, 290.0}, {33.0, 85.0}}, label: 'emptyStar'
```

The elements listed here, are the ones that are already visible when the cell is collapsed. When expanding the cell, i simply unhide the prevoiusly hidden elements.

This is my cell when it is [collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACyl3.png)
This is my cell when it is [expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkhZB.png)

Whats the problem here? Why are the elements accessible for me? 
(I did use a sleep(10) before printing out the elementtree to make sure that its not a timing issue)

**EDIT**
I figured out, that the problem is hiding and unhiding the views, not adding the views dynamically. If i unHide a view programmatically, it is NOT in my elementtree, but when i have it unHidden in the first place, it is there as it should...

Comment: @Tterheulle Whenver I have tried UI testing I end up getting different results. Try your testing on some other machine and it may work. I faced a similar issue where recording did'nt work on my personal mac, but it worked on the mac at my workplace.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is as Following: If you do this

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            //do some hiding of cell-views
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

the elementtree is not rebuild. Please do a

```
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [self.tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none) //when unhiding inside tableView.beginUpdates, the elementtree(testing) is not auto-rebuild
```

afterwards